# Decompressing .zip file in service makes app freeze until it finish decompressing, why?

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask, zip

I implemented the code to work with a async task and it works perfectly, but if user exits app it will get killed very fast, so I decided to try it with a service, it works perfectly, but it makes the app freeze.

So here's my decompress class:

```
    public class Decompress {
    private String _zipFile;
    private String _location;
    ZipEntry ze = null;

    public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
        _zipFile = zipFile;
        _location = location;

        _dirChecker("");
    }

    public void unzip() {
        try  {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                //Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

                if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                    _dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
                    for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                        fout.write(c);
                    }

                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();
                } 

            }
            zin.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
        }

    }

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(_location + dir);

        if(!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my service call for unzip:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
{

    try
    {
        zipFile = intent.getStringExtra("zipFile");
        zipLocation = intent.getStringExtra("unzipLocation");
        String fileS = intent.getStringExtra("file");
        file = new File(fileS);
        fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile); 
        zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

        while (zin.getNextEntry() != null) {
            numFiles++;
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {}
    catch (IOException e)
    {}

    d = new Decompress(zipFile, zipLocation);
    d.unzip();

}
```

Now here's how I ussed to call it with async task:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        d.unzip();

        return null;
    }
```

now my question is, why with async tsk my app don't get freeze and it will keep unzipping letting me cancel it with a button, but with service it makes the app lags? I even got a message about MyApp not responding, Would you like to close it?

EDIT: My service call for Start

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadFiles.this, MyService.class);
        String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/";
        String zipFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/test.zip"; 
        intent.putExtra("zipFile", zipFile);
        intent.putExtra("unzipLocation", unzipLocation);
        intent.putExtra("file", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/");
        startService(intent);

        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile); 
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

            while (zin.getNextEntry() != null) {
                 numFiles++;
                }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services **also** run in the UI (main) Thread, so you need to implement an AsyncTask or sepearate Thread approach there too.

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) say it all under **What is a Service?**

> A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

Edit: Note that if you start a Service from a background thread, the service is still running in the main thread. As per this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12740062/1815485). This should make sense as the docs say:

> When a Service component is actually created, for either of these
>   reasons, all that the system actually does is instantiate the
>   component and call its onCreate() and any other appropriate callbacks
>   on the **main thread**. It is up to the Service to implement these with
>   the appropriate behavior, such as creating a secondary thread in which
>   it does its work.

This ultimately means that you should always implement a seperate AsyncTask/Thread approach in Services as well, no matter how you start the Service.

Comment: I did add the call for the service in the sync task, sorry forgot to add it. Will edit my OP.

Comment: @RotaryHeart I updated my answer. Long story short, the Service is running in the Main Thread, even though the AsynTask launched it.

Comment: Amazing response and more amazing is that I had a Thread inside onStart(), but I didn't have thed d.unzip() inside it :) Working now

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in a separate background thread if you don't need the `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods of the AsyncTask, but still have a problem with the operation blocking the UI Thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        d = new Decompress(zipFile, zipLocation);
        d.unzip();
    }
};
t.start();
```

Simply starting the service from a background thread doesn't mean that it will be started off of the main UI thread. That is the default for its start, and you must create a new thread within the Service to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on A--C's point:
You need to create the background thread to unzip the file from *inside the service*, because the service is created and runs on the main thread, whether you start it inside another thread or not.

You basically need to do in the service exactly what you did outside the service (i.e. put the 'unzip' call inside the AsyncTask, and execute the task).

(Addendum)
The point of using a service is not to create a separate thread, but rather to split time-consuming processing from a UI-based application. It means that the UI can be destroyed by the OS and the resources recovered, and all the while the service is still running.
Thus, the decision about whether to use an AsyncTask (or thread) within the app itself vs within a service is really about whether the action should continue independently of the app interface or not. Restoring apps using TitaniumBackup is a good example of this: once you've started a restore, the app UI isn't really needed any more.

Comment: Perfect info for future builds :)